# Combinatorics Card problem .Which of the following solutions is correct?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I am working on the following problem:
In order to define a graph G = (V; E), consider a regular deck of 52 cards (lets's call the suits: A,B,C,D) and define the set V of nodes in the following way: a node $v \in V$ is any set of 3 cards that contains exactly one pair (that is two cards with the same value). For example, if $u = \{1A,1B,2C \}$;
$v = \{1D,1B,1A\}$; $w = \{1A,2B,3C\}$; then, $u \in V$ but $v$ and $w$  $\notin$ V . In the following we will
denote each $v \in V$ by $v = \{v1,v2,v3\}$, where $v1,v2$ correspond to the pair (that is, they have the same value) and $v3$ has a different value.
Compute the number of nodes

I found two ways of doing it, but I can't tell which is correct and why the other isn't:

1. I choose the pair number out of 13 numbers, then the 2 suits that make up the pair (that's 6 possibilities), then the number for the third card out of the 12 remaining numbers, and finaly the suit of the third card out of the possible 4 suits. Therefore: $13*6*12*4$
2. I choose one card out 52 as one the first card of the pair, this fixes the number for the second card of the pairs, for which I only have to chose the suit out of the remaing 3 suits, then the number for the third card out of the 12 remaining numbers, and finaly the suit of the third card out of the possible 4 suits
   Therefore: $52*3*12*4$

Any idea?

Comment: In your second approach, you are distinguishing the "first" card you choose for the pair from the "second" card, which you probably don't want to do: given a pair, either card can be "first."

Comment: oh I see now, thank you.